# Should even people with Hashimoto’s disease take potassium iodide in radiation emergencies?

Tags: radiation, potassium, hypothyroid, iodine, hashimoto-thyroiditis

In some radiation emergencies, [governments will recommend that people take potassium iodide](https://www.cdc.gov/nceh/radiation/emergencies/ki.htm) for a short time in pretty high doses to protect their thyroid against radiation damage and cancer.

But [iodine has adverse effects on some people with Hashimoto’s disease](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/endocrine-diseases/hashimotos-disease#diet).

Potassium iodide is surely different from pure iodine, but this still makes me wonder whether people with Hashimoto’s should follow those government recommendations.

Might the risks from the high dose of potassium iodide be worse than the radiation effects? Or is the potassium iodide form of iodine entirely harmless? Or is the risk from potassium iodide low enough that it pales in comparison to the risks that the radiation poses, especially since it’s only taken for a short time?

Thanks!

(Completely general question. I don’t have Hashimoto’s.)